# Azure Key Vault Operation get is not allowed on a disabled secret

Tags: asp.net-core, azure-keyvault

We have implemented Azure key vault in the .NET core application. Everything is working fine until we disabled the secret from the list - After my application tries to fetch the list again it started giving me the exception

```
Unhandled exception. Microsoft.Azure.KeyVault.Models.KeyVaultErrorException: Operation get is not allowed on a disabled secret.
   at Microsoft.Azure.KeyVault.KeyVaultClient.GetSecretWithHttpMessagesAsync(String vaultBaseUrl, String secretName, String secretVersion, Dictionary`2 customHeaders, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Microsoft.Azure.KeyVault.KeyVaultClientExtensions.GetSecretAsync(IKeyVaultClient operations, String secretIdentifier, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.AzureKeyVault.AzureKeyVaultConfigurationProvider.LoadAsync()
   at Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.AzureKeyVault.AzureKeyVaultConfigurationProvider.Load()
   at Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.ConfigurationRoot..ctor(IList`1 providers)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.ConfigurationBuilder.Build()
   at Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting.HostBuilder.BuildAppConfiguration()
   at Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting.HostBuilder.Build()
   at Vodafone.LandingPage.Program.Main(String[] args) in D:\a\1\s\src\LandingPage\Program.cs:line 30
```

Code I use to connect with Key Vault in program.cs file.

```
if (ctx.HostingEnvironment.IsProduction())
{
var builtConfig = builder.Build();

var keyVaultEndpoint = $"https://{builtConfig["AppSettings:KeyVaultName"]}.vault.azure.net/";
   

var azureServiceTokenProvider = new AzureServiceTokenProvider();
var keyVaultClient = new KeyVaultClient(
new KeyVaultClient.AuthenticationCallback(
azureServiceTokenProvider.KeyVaultTokenCallback));
builder.AddAzureKeyVault(keyVaultEndpoint, keyVaultClient, new DefaultKeyVaultSecretManager());
}
```

How we can restrict the list so that it will not take the disabled secrets together.
I am using "Get" and "List" permission.

Comment: You're looking at the wrong code.  The code that you pasted does not have a GetSecretAsync which is the code that is throwing the exception.  My guess is that you have another section of code which does both a List and a GetSecret and when the GetSecret happens on the disabled secret then it throws the exception.

---> Microsoft.Azure.KeyVault.KeyVaultClientExtensions.GetSecretAsync

Comment: I see that the code that is calling for the secret is likely calling this secret as part of the configuration... you need to check to see if this disabled secret is being called in your app settings.

Comment: @MattSmall Your are right. This code will read all secret and bind in configuration object. Can you help me how to bind configuration object with enabled secret only when my application start? If you can give me some example that will really help. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a research I found below solution.

You can use it like this

**Problem : Code which read all secret**

```
builder.AddAzureKeyVault(keyVaultEndpoint, keyVaultClient, new DefaultKeyVaultSecretManager());
```

**Solution : Code Which read only enabled secrets**

```
builder.AddAzureKeyVault(keyVaultEndpoint,keyVaultClient,new PrefixKeyVaultSecretManager(keyVaultEndpoint));
```

Implementation of IKeyVaultSecretManager

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
 using System.Text.RegularExpressions;
 using System.Threading.Tasks;
 using Microsoft.Azure.KeyVault;
 using Microsoft.Azure.KeyVault.Models;
 using Microsoft.Azure.Services.AppAuthentication;
 using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration;
 using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.AzureKeyVault;

namespace KeyVaultPOC
{

public class PrefixKeyVaultSecretManager : IKeyVaultSecretManager
{
    
    private readonly IList<string> _overrides = new List<string>();

    public PrefixKeyVaultSecretManager(string vaultUrl)
    {           

        Task.Run(() => LoadListOfOverrides(vaultUrl)).Wait();
    }

    private async Task LoadListOfOverrides(string vaultUrl)
    {
        var azureServiceTokenProvider = new AzureServiceTokenProvider();
        var keyVaultClient = new KeyVaultClient(
            new KeyVaultClient.AuthenticationCallback(azureServiceTokenProvider.KeyVaultTokenCallback)
        );
                    
        var secrets = await keyVaultClient.GetSecretsAsync(vaultUrl);
        bool moreSecrets;

        do
        {
            foreach (var secret in secrets)
            {                    
                if ((bool)secret.Attributes.Enabled)
                {
                    _overrides.Add(secret.Identifier.Name);
                }
            }

            moreSecrets = !string.IsNullOrEmpty(secrets.NextPageLink);

            if (moreSecrets)
            {
                secrets = await keyVaultClient.GetSecretsNextAsync(secrets.NextPageLink);
            }
        } while (moreSecrets);
    }

    public bool Load(SecretItem secret)
    {
        
        return true;
    }

    public string GetKey(SecretBundle secret)
    {
        var key = secret.SecretIdentifier.Name;

        

        return key;
    }
}
```

}

Ref : https://gist.github.com/davidxcheng/0576659d2c876d299619d979767dcdd6